# SourceTree not pushing and taking space

Tags: git, sourcetree

So I decided to turn my Raspberry Pi into a Git server.

I installed the stuff and source tree on my windows PC. My project is rather large(12 GB), but as I had about 50gb free then I figured that I was ok.

So I copied everything over to my git folder and committed. The commit seemed to have worked but it fails to push as it says that it's out of memory.

"fatal: Out of memory, malloc failed (tried to allocate 388031557 bytes)"

I tried a few changes to this, one that told me to add some stuff to my config file. I then tried that and pushed again, the problem is that every push seems to take up 12 GB more. And I have no idea where these files are stored, I just know that they're not in the git directory of my project.

Now I can't push anymore as I don't have enough memory to try again, and I don't know where the files are stored. I also don't know how to solve the "out of memory" problem.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: I managed to clear up the disk space by running "sudo git prune".

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to push directly from the terminal instead of use Sourcetree?

Regards

Andoni

Comment: No, I have not. But I can't pull anymore as I'm out of HDD space.

Comment: Sorry I meant push.